# What to use in NodeJS to create process which works long time and is accessible during its lifetime

Tags: node.js, express

I want to create some process which will work for a long time and it will be possible to obtain data from this process by get request.

Comment: You can spawn child processes and pass data back-and-forth from your main process like this: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process

Comment: Take a look at [`forever`](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) or [`pm2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2).